# How do I name a Rails ruby file whose class name has numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can a Rails class name contain numbers? For example:

```
class Test123
end
```

Is this a valid class? I get an `uninitialized constant Test123` error when I try to load the class.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: `uninitialized constant Test123`. Does that mean it's not valid? @minitech says that it is.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk: Can you show the exact code that produces that error, please?

Comment: `class Test123 def run(params) end end` is the class code. `"Test123".constantize.run(params)` is when it is being called. This only happens when the class name contains `123`.

Comment: Correction for above. It's actually `"Test123".constantize.new.run(params)`.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It could not find the class because the class file was not named correctly. I had `test_123.rb` but it should be `test123.rb` instead.

Comment: Rails seems to treat numbers like lowercase letters in this case.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think Artem Kalinchuk's last comment deserves to be the answer of this misworded question.

A Ruby class name can contain numbers.

A **Rails** class has to be defined in a correctly named file. If I define a class called `NewYear2012Controller`:

Correct file name: `new_year2012_controller.rb`
Incorrect file name: `new_year_2012_controller.rb` (note the extra underscore)

Because this is how Rails inflector and auto-loading works.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, [Ruby class names may contain numbers](http://codepad.org/FsBMiOS9). However, as with all identifiers in Ruby, [they may not begin with numbers](http://codepad.org/tbcuM6tJ).

[Reference](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#ident):

> ## Identifiers
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> foobar    ruby_is_simple
> ```
>
> Ruby identifiers are consist of alphabets,
> decimal digits, and the underscore character, and begin with a
> alphabets(including underscore). There are no restrictions on the
> lengths of Ruby identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

- rename your model and model.rb file
- add table_name magic

as here:

```
class TwoProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = '2_products'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this...

See the following

```
class Ab123
  def initialize(y) 
    @z = y 
  end
end

class AbCde
  def initialize(y) 
    @z = y 
  end
end
```

and the following instantiations:

```
Ab123.new x
```

or

```
AbCde.new x
```

Only the latter `AbCde.new x` instantiates properly.

Comment: In Rails, it's one class per file if you want this to work properly, and the file name must match the class name using the appropriate rules.